# Linea divisora entre dos secciones (colores solidos) - CSS

Tags: html, css

Quiero lograr el efecto que figura en la imagen, que quede esa división entre el color amarillo y el color blanco, he intentado con el `background-image: linear-gradient()` pero sólo me crea la linea divisora dentro del `div` amarillo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Acabo de encontrar la respuesta 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352311/how-do-i-draw-a-diagonal-div

Comment: me alegra que encontraras una solución. por favor pon eso como respuesta (con más información, no solo en enlace). Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: He hecho algo parecido en algunos sitios usando linear-gradient con el before/after. Luego veo si de eso va la respuesta que encontraste (estoy en móvil y se hace difícil). Y te pongo una respuesta si no lo es.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He realizado diseños parecidos usando `linear-gradient` junto con los pseudo-elementos `::before` y `::after`. La idea es  dejar un espacio abajo del contenedor (usando `padding`) y entonces colocar el pseudo-elemento de forma absoluta y con un `linear-gradient` que vaya de la esquina superior izquierda a la esquina inferior  derecha (dejando un porcentaje mínimo entre los valores para que no se vea un corte brusco).

Aquí lo puedes ver:

```css
section {
  min-height: 100px;
}

section.dark {
  background: #beeeef;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

section.dark::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #beeeef 50%, #fff 50.1%);
}
```

```html
<section class="dark">
  Sección 1
</section>
<section>
  Sección 2
</section>
```

También se puede hacer sin necesidad de pseudo-elementos: poniéndole directamente un `linear-gradient` al contenedor. El problema es que vas a tener que calcular los valores dependiendo del ancho de la pantalla o puede que no se vea bien.